# How to get yDomain value in ReactVis

Tags: react-vis

In **React-vis**, I display the cursor position of the mouse using a `LineSeries`. I would like it to extend along *all* the vertical extent of the `FlexibleXYPlot` in which it's included:

[Image of the cursor on a ReactVis plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcejC.png)

¿How can I get the value of the `yDomain` of the plot?

Thank you!

### Edit

I am using **React-vis** in **clojurescript**. I got the line seen in the first image with this code:

```
[:> rvis/LineSeries {:data [{:x @nearest-x :y y-min}{:x @nearest-x :y y-max}]
                     :strokeStyle "dashed" :color "black"
                     :opacity (if @button-pressed? .5 0)}]
```

And I needed to compute the value of `y-min` and `y-max` (that was the meaning of my question).

But then I realized that I can use the `Crosshair` facility:

```
[:> rvis/Crosshair {:values [{:x @nearest-x :y 0}] 
                    :style {:line {:opacity (if @button-pressed? .5 0)}}}
                   [:div]]
```

[Crosshair in React-vis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ck5Uy.png)

It's difficult to see (it's under the cursor), because I still can't manage to change its color. I thought that this would work:

```
[:> rvis/Crosshair {:values [{:x @nearest-x :y 0}] 
                    :style {:line {:color "#000"
                                   :opacity (if @button-pressed? .5 0)}}}
                   [:div]]
```

But it doesn't. I think this would be another question. :)

### Edit 2

It was `:background "black"` instead of `:color "black"`. I got it reading the file `plot.scss`. :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @rottweiler: Thanks for your interest! I just have done so.